# Different branding for same codebase

Tags: reactjs, less, webpack

Im in a project where we will create different sites using the same codebase. 
I would like to have a brand style and config for each site which I specify somehow in my build process.

Anyone have an idea of the best way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would treat the different sites in much the same way I'd treat different environment (dev, test, prod). If there aren't a lot of changes, just use environment variables on each server where the site will run that define which site it is. Your code can then conditionally do things (e.g. add a class `site-x` to the body for styling).

You can use something like [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to make setting environment vars easier (remember Windows does it differently to *NIX) if you're setting environments in a script. That way you're changing a file rather then actual environment variables when you want to test what a particular site looks like.

If there are many different config items that are different between sites then you can have multiple config files (`config-site-one.js`, `config-site-two.js`) and a central `config.js` file that returns the correct config based on some environment variable like `MY_SITE_NAME`.

However if you actually want to package up the site to 'send' somewhere (?) then you could run your build command with a flag like `webpack blahblahblah --site=site-one`.

You can use [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) to get that 'site' variable and use it in your build process however you like.

Comment: Thanks, the links gave me some ideas for sure :)